# Odoo8 Integrity Error while adding calendar view

Tags: odoo-8

In odoo 8.0, I am working on Hotel Management module but while adding calendar view to display reservations why I have this kind of error like,

> IntegrityError: insert or update on table "hotel_restaurant_order"
>   violates foreign key constraint
>   "hotel_restaurant_order_waiter_name_fkey" DETAIL:  Key
>   (waiter_name)=(10) is not present in table "res_partner".